# Eclipse Application tab

Tags: android, eclipse

**When I open my project manifest and select the application tab, it is a blank tab!**

[image: application tab]

**And in the manifest, I don't have Application nodes so I cant insert or edit the activities by this form.**

[image: manifest]

**My Eclipse version is 3.6.2**

**Whats the problem?**

**Why is the application tab blank?**

Comment: It happens sometimes, try to close the tab and reopen it, and see if it works.

Comment: @Egor Thanks for replying, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

so strange! Maybe you should be download the new version eclipse 4.2

Comment: thanks for replying, but its a little hard to update the eclipse because of large amount of the softwares that I have to  download and install them on eclipse again.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- Open the application tab then while this tab is open, close eclipse IDE.
- Run eclipse

Its strange but it works!

[image]